# Pandas - Python Remodel the Date Column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a date column like this in my pandas data-frame.

My DataFrame looks like this,

```
ID  SerialDate
1   2008-1-15
2   T1
3   2008-1-17
4    T1
```

T1 is the only text that will be found in this column and there won't be any blanks.The dtype of this column is object

I need to change this to look like,

Expected dataframe :-

```
ID SerialDate
 1  15/01/2008
 2  T1
 3  17/01/2008
 4  T1
```

Expected dtype :-Object.

How can I do this using Pandas. I would prefer a user defined function something like df[colb] = requiredfunction(df,colb)

Comment: so is this a dataframe/series with a single column that looks something like: `["2008-1-15", "T1", "2008-1-17", "T1"]` if it were a list? Are the T1s and dates mixed? And is the "2008-1-15" a datetime object or a string?

Comment: Yes it would like that if it were a list. They are all strings and they are mixed @SvenHarris

Comment: @SvenHarris Updated the question now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily generate the required output with basic string operations and apply function of pandas

```
df['SerialDate'] = df['SerialDate'].apply(lambda x:'/'.join(x.split('-')[::-1]))
```

In your particular case, 'T1' is also not affected by this operation.

Explanation:

what does `[::-1]` do?

```
>> [1,2,3][::-1]
>> [3,2,1]
```

It reverses an array

To convert x -> 0x

```
df['SerialDate'] = df['SerialDate'].apply(lambda x:'/'.join([y.zfill(2) for y in x.split('-')[::-1]]))
```

Comment: Just one more thing please - how can I convert 1/1/2001 to 01/01/2001 on the same line that you provided. I need it to 01/01/2001. 0 is not getting added. Thanks.

Comment: @Sid29 the edit should work, but remember that if the characters 'T1' is replaced with something else it has to be atleast 2 characters to work. In your case you need not worry about this.

Answer (score 2):

Using `to_datetime` with `strftime` then we mask back with original column

```
df=pd.read_clipboard()
s=pd.to_datetime(df.SerialDate,errors = 'coerce').dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
df.SerialDate=s.mask(s=='NaT',df.SerialDate)
df
Out[402]: 
   ID  SerialDate
0   1  15/01/2008
1   2          T1
2   3  17/01/2008
3   4          T1
```

Comment: can you please adjust the expected output as per the question. Thanks.